# Having error on working with 64bit data types

Tags: c++

I have a code that has a function something like the above code, When I run this code and input the value of the string as something like `265.145`, it works normally, but when I input the value as big as `5415485451447454554545415454.84845151151511515151515151`.

It throws an error saying `terminate called after throwing an instance of ‘std out of range’ what():stoull`.

```
#include<iostream

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string y;

    cin>>y;

    int64_t z;

    z=stoull(y); 

    double x=stod(y);

    double d= x-z;

    cout<<d;

}
```

Comment: Your second value looks like it's larger than the maximum value an `int64_t` can hold, as the error helpfully states. What do you _think_ should happen when you try to read a value too large to be held in an `int64_t`?

Comment: Are you just trying to figure out the part after the decimal point? If so it would be simpler to delete up to there in the string and then convert that to a double directly.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes I am trying to do that , but could you please explain in a bit detail as to how can i do that

Comment: Everything you read via `cin` is a string. You can use string functions/methods to change a string to your desire. Read about "how to manipulate strings?".

Answer (score 1):

The document of [stoull](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) shows that we will get an exception when the converted value is out of range:

```
Exceptions
            * std::invalid_argument if no conversion could be performed
            * std::out_of_range if the converted value would fall out of the range of the
              result type or if the underlying function (std::strtoul or std::strtoull) sets
              errno to ERANGE.
```

The maximum value one `int64_t` type can hold on x86_64 platform is `9223372036854775807` (`std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max()`), for your use case the input file is larger than the maximum value, you need a big int type, which is not provided as a primitive type.

I recommend using a library like `boost`, the `multiprecision` library in boost have multiple backends, this example uses `cpp_int`, it's a header only library(You only need to include the header, no linkage needed!)

If you haven't got any experience with `boost`, you need to install it first:

- For ubuntu like disto, just use command `sudo apt install libboost-dev`
- For Windows, just [follow this guide](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/more/getting_started/windows.html), or use package manager like: [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/boost/) or [vcpkg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/manage-libraries-with-vcpkg)

```cpp
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>

int main() {
  using namespace boost::multiprecision;
  std::string str = "5415485451447454554545415454.84845151151511515151515151";
  std::istringstream oss(str);
  cpp_int u;
  oss >> u;
  std::cout << u << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WKMs53cea).