# Rounding off large decimal numbers

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  long double a;
  cin>>a;
  int64_t itg=int64_t(a);
  long double d=a-itg;
    if(d==0)
        cout<<itg;
    if(d>=0.5)
        cout<<itg+1;
    if(d<0.5&&d>0)
        cout<<itg;
}
```

I am trying to round off decimal numbers ,but i am having problem with large decimal numbers, like
" 84939825309432908832902189.9092309409809091329".When I input this value, the output is like "-9223372036854775807", Otherwise if i input some normal number, it works fine.

Comment: `int64_t` can only hold numbers about up to 10^18 (10 to the power of 18), your number is far above that.

Comment: your value is larger than an `int64_t`, why not just use `std::round` or `std::floor`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Having error on working with 64bit data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67497973/having-error-on-working-with-64bit-data-types)

Comment: @AlanBirtles I tried it but it is returning the value in e , i want the exact value

Comment: @Aquib Use `std::cout<<std::fixed`

Answer (score 1):

your number is out of range of `int_64`.
if you want to deal with large numbers like that, 1 approach is treat it like a string and proceed that string as you want.
for example, with your problems above, you can read the string, take digit right after the `'.'` character, and compare it with `'5'`.
here is an example on [Geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/) with [Multiply Large Numbers represented as Strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiply-large-numbers-represented-as-strings/)